# Add axis title for iplot equation

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

How to add graph title, x and y axis title for iplot equation?

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import numpy as np
init_notebook_mode()

x = np.linspace(-5,20)
iplot([{'x': x, 'y': 4-0.325/(1+14/x)**3}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    title="Title",
    xaxis=dict(
        title="X Label"
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Y label"
    ) 
)

x = np.linspace(-5,20)
iplot({'data': [{'x': x, 'y': 4-0.325/(1+14/x)**3}], 'layout': layout})
```